# Восстановление базы данных MSSQL через pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, odbc

Есть функция принимающая полный путь к файлу backup'a.

```
def restore_database(full_path_archive_file: str):
    current_datetime = datetime.now()
    connection_string= f"""DRIVER={Config.driver};
                         SERVER={Config.server};
                         DATABASE={Config.database};
                         UID={Config.username}];
                         PWD={Config.password};
                         Trusted_Connection=yes;
                         autocommit=True;"""
    # коннект к БД
    conn = connect(connection_string)
    # курсор для взаимодействия с SQL сервером
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    # восстановление БД из backup'a
    cursor.execute(f"""ALTER DATABASE {Config.database} SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
                       use master;
                       RESTORE DATABASE {Config.database}
                       FROM DISK = '{full_path_archive_file}'
                       WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY;
                       ALTER DATABASE {Config.database} SET MULTI_USER;""")
    # выборка с системной таблицы (здесь я хочу убедится что БД восстановилась успешно)
    cursor.execute(f"""SELECT [restore_date], [user_name] FROM [msdb].[dbo].[restorehistory]
                       WHERE user_name=\'{Config.username}\' AND
                       restore_date > '{current_datetime.strftime('%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S')}'""")
    # полученные строки из БД (возвращает кортежи)
    found_database_restore = cursor.fetchall()
    if not found_database_restore:
        raise Exception(f'Не удалось восстановить базу данных.')
    conn.close()
```

Вылетает на строчке :

```
cursor.execute(f"""ALTER DATABASE {Config.database} SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
                   use master;
                   RESTORE DATABASE {Config.database}
                   FROM DISK = '{full_path_archive_file}'
                   WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY;
                   ALTER DATABASE {Config.database} SET MULTI_USER;""")
```

Ошибка :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "***\__main__.py", line 78, in <module>
    restore_database(new_path_archive)
  File "***\__main__.py", line 49, in restore_database
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]
Инструкцию ALTER DATABASE нельзя использовать в транзакции из нескольких инструкций. (226) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Попытался выполнить то же самое в SQL скрипте указывая путь файла в ручную.
База была восстановлена успешно. (проверил из [msdb].[dbo].[restorehistory])

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: `cursor.execute()` - умеет выполнять только __одну__ команду и не понимает символа ';'. Поэтому вам придется запускать каждую команду в отдельном вызове `cursor.execute()`

Comment: @MaxU, спасибо.